# Installing ionic on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I am trying to install `ionic` on windows 10 with the following command `npm install -g cordova ionic` but I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.5
npm ERR! code EADDRINUSE
npm ERR! errno EADDRINUSE
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect EADDRINUSE 151.101.16.162:80 - Local (undefined:undefined)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

contents of the log is [npm-debug.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/limpep/25c672fbfbd9e5ee35ea5235dfe8c648/raw/8985ad8671c8d13b3d06c649de98b1e139d912a2/npm-debug.log)

my currently system path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\‌​Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\gradle-2.13-all\gradle-2.13\bi‌​n;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

if anyone can help that would be great

Comment: What have you already tried to solve your issue? There are already several hints/solutions by googling your error.